# “Dankeschön” or “Danke schön”?

Tags: difference, spelling

I’ve seen some people spell ‘thank you’ *Dankeschön*, and others *Danke schön*, so I was wondering, which is it?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dankeschoen, https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dankesch%C3%B6n

Comment: @hellcode That link doesn't give the information this question asks and the below answer answers. Your link only has the noun form. What is the "general reference" that provides the command form (or whatever is the proper way to say the form of "thank you" when expressed as a response to a favor done)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase *danke schön!* is written in two words, and both are generally lowercase, as they are a verb and an adjective:

> Vielen Dank, danke schön!
>   Danke schön, das ist sehr freundlich!
>   Können Sie mir vielleicht sagen, wie spät es ist? – Ja, genau zehn Uhr, auf die Minute. – Danke schön.

However, the noun *Dankeschön* is written in one word and capitalized (like all nouns):

> Als kleines Dankeschön für Ihre Mühe möchte ich Ihnen diesen Blumenstrauß überreichen.
>   Ein großes Dankeschön geht auch an den Hausmeister.